# Linux mint. Настройка горячих клавиш, включающих другие комбинации

Tags: linux, hotkeys

Пытался гуглить в разных вариантах, но даже не могу нормально вопрос сформулировать.

Изменение языка настроено через <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>. Есть ли возможность использовать это же сочетание + [другая кнопка] для выполнения другого действия без переключения языка?

Например, в моей IDE по умолчанию поиск по файлам стоит как <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>, но если с моей конфигурацией переключения языка использовать эту комбинацию, то в том числе поменяется и язык. В Windows этот фокус работает нормально - поиск открывается, язык не меняется.

Собственно вопрос, можно ли заставить Linux (Mint) дожидаться пока будет введена вся комбинация клавиш, которую я хотел? Условно, отрабатывать событие по keyup.

P.s. Все свои локальные настройки всех своих локальных приложений я в состоянии переделать без использования <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Comment: Ну, где-то в настройках винды вроде есть способ поменять горячие клавиши. Если не путаю, языковая панель - параметры - переключение клавиатуры.

Comment: Это известная "фича" обработчика клавиатуры `setxkbmap`: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/setxkbmap/-/issues/10#note_1619232
Когда я пользовался Linux-ом, то не стал бороться, а настроил переключать раскладку `Win+Space`

Comment: Я вообще пользуюсь `CTRL`+`Shift`.

Comment: Кстати, удалите из своего вопроса метку [горячие-клавиши]. Есть уже [hot-keys]. Замучаешься потом синонимизировать.

Comment: @PakUula почитал что вы скинули. Видимо вы правы, в данном случае, к сожалению, проще просто смириться с этим...